# Search Crawl rule for single site library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, search, content-search-web-part

I have SharePoint site collection with multiple sub sites. I need to write crawl rule for searching the content for the particular sub site alone. Is it possible in SharePoint 2007? If yes,could you help me to resolve this.

Thanks,

Comment: I am curious why you would want to cripple search in this way. What is the business case?

Comment: The architecture has multi level sub sites so we need to write the crawl rule according to that

Comment: Don't you want to find the content in the sub sites?

Comment: Yes i need to find the content too

Comment: If you exclude the content from the sub-sites with a crawl rule you will not find the content because it will not be included in the index.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a crawl rule to only crawl the URL of the single sub-site. On the add a crawl rule page, in the path section, enter the path to the site with a /* at the end, e.g.

https://sharepoint.domain.com/subsite1/*

(change the URL to match what you want to crawl on your system)

Select the 'include all items in this path' option.

Note that you should test the crawl rules that have been configured. On the Manage Crawl Rules page, enter a URL for an item within the sub-site you want to crawl to ensure that it will be crawled, then enter something outside that to ensure that it will not be crawled.

Note that you may have to modify the start addresses for your crawl sources to ensure that only specific web applications are crawled. You may also need to provide a crawl rule to exclude all content within a specific area, then the crawl rule above to include only a subset of the content.

The key really is testing. Try your crawl rule(s) and test the configuration with URLs both inside the area to be crawled and outside to ensure that you're getting the expected result before actually starting the crawl itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response, we have nested sub sites available under my site collection, in this scenario how can I make crawl rule
eg: https://sharepoint.domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/sbusite3

Comment: It depends which part(s) of that structure you want to crawl. If only the bottom part, use only that URL in the crawl rule (https://sharepoint.domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/subsite3/*) however if you want to crawl subsite2 without crawling subsite3, you'd need several rules, one to include https://sharepoint.domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/* and more to exclude https://sharepoint.domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/subsite3/* (and any other subsites of subsite 2 you want to exclude).

Comment: I have clarification on this,  for example i have 100 sub sites with different name means i need to mention each and every one in crawl rule?
Ex: sharepoint.domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/sbusite3
sharepoint.domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/sbusite4
sharepoint.domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/sbusite5

Like this I need to mention in the rule section?

Comment: If they all have the same style of URL, you should be able to use something like https://sharepoint.domain.com/subsite1/subsite2/subsite* although I've not personally tried that. Try that as a rule and then test a sample URL to see whether it will be crawled

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to only crawl special libraries. As an suggestion, you can create search scope to limit search results from special document libraries.

Comment: Crawl rules make it possible.